# Calling C from COBOL: trouble with stderr

Tags: c, cobol, hp-nonstop, tandem

From my COBOL program, I'm calling my C module which itself makes calls to a proprietary library. This library insists on writing to `stderr`, although there's no `stderr` available since the main program is written in COBOL. Consequently, the program aborts with this message:

```
cannnot open stderr
```

The support guys at HP advised me to issue

```
PARAM SAVE-ENVIRONMENT ON
```

in TACL before running the program. This indeed solved my problem. However, my program will be used by several people in a number of scripts and I don't want to force them to issue `PARAM SAVE-ENVIRONMENT ON` prior to running the program.

Is there some COBOL85 directive which allows me to properly run the program without changing any parameters manually? Something like

```
?PARAM SAVE-ENVIRONMENT ON
```

would be great...

EDIT:

Since I'm able to modify the C module (*not* the library), I'd be completely satisfied with a C-based solution. However, simply opening `stderr` before calling the library didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I gather that you're unable to modify the C library, since otherwise that would seem like an obvious option... In that case, does it really make sense to tag C into this? The same problem could be experienced when using a C++ library. Does that mean you should tag C++, too?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: I'm unable to modify the C library. However, I'm able to modify the C module which is calling the C library, so if there's a solution based on modifying the C module, I'd be happy too.

Comment: Your HP-Non-Stop/Tandem is not a "Mainframe" in the meaning of the Tag. If you could remove that, it would reduce possible confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PARAM SAVE-ENVIRONMENT ON` makes HP COBOL-programs save environment variables (which they receive as messages at startup from Guardian) for future calls to `getenv()` from C modules.

Actually, the library I'm using tries to open `stderr` because it can't read environment variables. One solution is to set the `PARAM SAVE-ENVIRONMENT` to `ON`, so `getenv()` will properly function again. This has to be done in each TACL session.

Unless: you use the `?SAVE STARTUP`- or `?SAVE ALL`-directive in your COBOL program to achieve the same effect.

Lessons learned:

- Don't mix COBOL and C.
- Don't use COBOL at all.

Comment: Are there "downsides" to using the ?SAVE stuff? Your Cobol compiler might be very outdated (I saw some Tandem stuff last September, and it was Cobol '74). If you have "old" programs there, you may not be able to avoid Cobol, so best to find out (which perhaps you have) how to get it to work with C. You may find yourself surprised by the relative performance between C and Cobol with the type of datafailes which exist at your site :-)

Comment: Actually, the company *wants* COBOL programs (except in a few rare cases). About 90% of our codebase is COBOL, and after a few months of working here, I have to admit that COBOL is perfectly suited for the task at hand. It's just so awfully ugly. But apart from the issue reported here, I'm amazed how nicely it interfaces with C.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to elevate the ?SAVE STARTUP and ?SAVE ALL directives ? I think that they are the real answer to your original question, the other part is mainly a restatement of your original question.  (Congratulations on figuring this out - by the time you have worked through native/non-native, CRE/non-CRE, OSS/Guardian in the manual its often tempting to throw in the towel with these mixed language problems.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute TACL commands from Cobol, that could do it.

Can you open a file in Cobol assinged to stderr? Perhaps discovering exactly what PARAM SAVE-ENVIRONMENT ON does might help as well.

Most of the C contributors are not going to know the operating system on the HP/Tandem, which is going to impact the worth of answers. I have no idea if you can "shell out" from your C program to issue a TACL command or run a TACL script.

A bit of research with your Cobol, TACL, and C manuals for the HP/Tandem might lead you to answers, perhaps a google or two as well.

What is the problem with including the statement in their scripts anyway? If they want the program to work?

Comment: `PARAM SAVE-ENVIRONMENT ON` makes COBOL-programs save environment variables (which they receive as messages at startup) for future calls to `getenv()` from C modules. Actually, the library I'm using tries to open `stderr` because it can't read environment variables. See my answer for a full description.

Answer (score 1):

Not being an HP NonStop developer, I have some questions.  stderr is a special symbol in C.  File channel 2 (0 standard in, 1 standard out, 2 standard error), but those are low level channel numbers.  stderr is a default pointer to a FILE structure. Falling back to GNU/Linux, /usr/include/stdio.h defines them as

```
/* Standard streams.  */
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdin;          /* Standard input stream.  */
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdout;         /* Standard output stream.  */
extern struct _IO_FILE *stderr;         /* Standard error output stream.  */
/* C89/C99 say they're macros.  Make them happy.  */
#define stdin stdin
#define stdout stdout
#define stderr stderr
```

Opening a file named "stderr" isn't the same thing. Any process that is created should have 0, 1, and 2 already open. Should not matter what programming language is used for main. Is HP NonStop that much different than other POSIX-ey systems?  stderr (the FILE pointer) is usually global to any code that includes stdio.h

As an aside, coming from an OpenCOBOL and GNU/Linux fanboy:
Regarding your other comment on lessons learned,

- DO mix COBOL and C (and Fortran, and Ada, and Vala, and Python, and Java and ...)
- DO use COBOL

Comment: I like your post! As for your question: The HP NonStop OS comes in two so-called personalities, Guardian and OSS. At my company, we're using Guardian, which makes MS-DOS look like a POSIX reference implementation. The C compiler is largely ISO-conformant, and the C library implements a large portion of POSIX. However, in order to exploit those features that make the HP NonStop $500.000 more expensive than a PC, you are forced to sacrifice portability. HP substantially extended both ISO C and POSIX up to a point where you barely recognize that you're looking at C source.

Comment: And you are right, `stderr` is usually globally visible. However, it's the job of the standard C library's startup code to assign some useful value to it, which it doesn't unless the main entry point was created by C code, at least here. Both Guardian and COBOL85 don't implement the concept of `stderr`.